# Regex expression for at least one upper, lower and digit

Tags: regex, passwords

Can anybody help me with a regex expession to check the following criteria?

The criteria is one(or more) cap letter, one (or more)lower letter and one (or more) digit. It must be more than 6 characters

What I have is

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).+.{6,}$
```

Am I on the right track? Keep in mind that I want it to allow symbols too

Thanks

Comment: Did you get the right result? Just remove that `.+` and it will be fine.

Comment: More than 6 characters, or at least 6 characters?

Comment: [xkcd Password Strength](https://xkcd.com/936/)

Comment: `.+.{6,}` can be simplified to `.{7,}`.

Comment: You can test your regexp here: http://regexr.com?35hu0

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are on the right track..

Just remove `.+` from your regex,it is redundant and doesn't really add anything to the regex

If you want to match **more** than 6 characters you should use `.{7,}`